# Linux Ubuntu directory root? home?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory

I know it is very simple thing! but i cannot understand!

what is difference between two directory?

i know when i use `cd ~/`, i can go home directory

like this

```
ubuntu@ip-MY IP :~$
```

and then i use `cd ../`

i can go `ubuntu@ip-MY IP:/home$`

and after one more time

then i located `ubuntu@ip- MY IP :/$`

what this directory's role

please explain that 3 directory above!

Comment: If you think of the directory structure as a tree, the *root directory* `/` is the root of the tree. Everything spreads out from it like branches of a tree. The root directory is also the only directory that doesn't have a parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

The `/` is a root directory of the file system - the toppest inod of the tree. `/home` is typically a directory where the home directories of the users of the system are located. One of those users is the user with name `root`. But he is a bit special, therefore, he may have his home directory located separately from the other users (i.e. in security reasons). Then, this directory can be `/root`, or in the simplest case just `/` (so, it is the root of the system, and a home directory of the user with the name root at the same time). Hopefully this solves your confusion.